# Зависает Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Какие могут быть причины зависания Ubuntu? В интернете читал, что обычно может зависать графическая оболочка, но в моём случае зависает, скорей всего, система, так как консоль не запускается.

Comment: по минимальным требованиям подходит ?

Comment: проверьте смарт hdd, посмотрите логи OS по времени, во время подвисания обратите внимание как реагирует индикатор hdd.

Comment: Что значит "консоль не запускается" ? У меня например бывают проблемы с видюхой и графической оболочкой, в 90% случаев я успешно переключаюсь в текстовую консоль по "Ctrl+Alt+F1", и перезапускаю графику `killall Xorg`. В 10% случаев зависает вместе с клавиатурой и переключится не получается

Comment: Ну вот у меня как в этих 10% случаев, переключится невозможно

Comment: сервисы какие-нибудь отвечают? (icmp, ssh, etc). Если ничто не отвечает, то перезапустите систему и смотрите логи

Comment: К сожалению, отладка операционной системы, не входит в тематику StackOverflow. О проблемах с Линукс можно спросить на сайте superuser.com/ из англоязычной сети StackExchange. В рунете есть прекрасные форумы linux.org.ru и opennet.ru.

Answer (score 3):

подробнее опишите симптомы, версию os, пожалуйста. есть ли вторая операционная система на компьютере?

в целом алгоритм такой:

если доходим до выбора вариантов операционной системы/версий ядра, вы находитесь в загрузчике grub.
Выбираете последний Ubuntu, жмете `e` (подсказка внизу), в редакторе находите строчки

> `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

если есть, то и

> `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`

меняете на

> `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="--verbose nosplash debug"`
>
> `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="--verbose nosplash debug"`

смотрите на ошибки.

если есть возможность загрузиться с флэшки: находите ваш жесткий диск / ssd, идете глазками смотреть `/var/log/boot.log`, `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`

если нужно читать логи systemd, то с флэшки это можно сделать `journalctl -D путь_к_каталогу_с_логами`

если не доходит даже до загрузчика - вероятно - у вас полетел mbr (дохнет диск, перезаписала винда, случайно сами что-то удалили)

частые причины ошибок:

- драйвера видеокарт после обновлений системы.
- неправильное обновление системы из-за того, что установили левые репозитории, после этого часть системных библиотек обновилась, часть нет, а вместе они работать уже не могут (это и на видео повлиять может, кстати). Детектируется, как правило тем, что не работает `apt-get update && apt-get install`
- слетевший загрузчик/mbr

как лечить (из того что мне попадалось):

- если полетели драйвера видео: грузитесь в `Advanced options for Ubuntu`, грузитесь в консоль, с флэшки или с помощью текстового браузера скачиваете видео-драйвер и, соответственно инструкции по установке, ставите его в консольном режиме.  (или сносите просто)
- неправильное обновление системы - самое плохое, что мне попадалось, точных рецептов нет, я однажды часов 6 потратил просто из принципа, чтобы вылечить. обычно просто переустанавливают систему.
- mbr(загрузчик/grub) - google.

p.s., если вы загрузились с флэшки и видите рабочий стол и находите ваш жесткий диск, возрадуйтесь, диск жив и видеокарта не сдохла. а переключаться в консоль не получается из-за зависших видео-драйверов. т.е. можете попробовать, например, сделать `ctrl+alt+f1` и вслепую набрать `cd / ; sudo updateb; find .`   скорее всего, вы увидите как индикатор hdd мигает. значит система жива

еще советую - на будущее - настроить (аккуратно) sshd чтобы можно было залогиниться на компьютер без флэшки просто из локальной сети (или - если настраивали аккуратно и пробросили порты - хоть через мобильник) и поправить настройки

p.s один из самых лучших индикаторов зависшей системы - реакция на нажатие сaps lock. если маленькая лампочка  загорается - не все так плохо. Если не работает, оч плохо, придется основательно лечить.

Comment: отличная инструкция по диагностике проблем, возникающих при загрузке! но только вопрос, насколько я понял, касается отнюдь не **процесса загрузки**, а зависания **уже загруженной** операционной системы.

Comment: тут не известно, к сожалению `так как консоль не запускается.` может означать что угодно( Если у автора не работает переключение из графического режима в консольный - то надо это уточнить, но тогда и ответ, скорее всего, простой - проблема  на 90% в видео-драйвере, тогда надо смотреть в логи xorg, либо (кажется команда такая) -  `apt-get purge название_драйвера`,  либо загрузиться с флэшки с дефлотными дровами и проверить переключение

Comment: автор вопроса уточняет в [комментарии](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/531837/#comment663711_531837), что ему не удаётся переключиться на виртуальный терминал (с помощью `ctrl+alt+f*`).

Comment: скорее всего рецепт будет либо как в комменте выше, либо как в одном из наших ответов. переключение видеорежима происходит и при загрузке тоже. Ну т.е. ему придется смотреть в те же логи и грузиться в текстовом режиме в ту же самую консоль, а не через x-терминал скорее всего (если nvidia, то она его заставит убить Xorg и зайти в консоль)

Answer (score -1):

> Какие могут быть причины зависания Ubuntu?

*ubuntu* — это имя собственное одного из [дистрибутивов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2) операционной системы *gnu/linux*. к дистрибутиву как таковому понятие «завис» вообще неприменимо.

а «зависла» у вас, судя по симптомам, программа *linux*.

первейшее средство диагностики проблем, с которыми сталкивается эта программа — её кольцевой буфер сообщений. просмотреть его содержимое можно программой [*dmesg*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dmesg). естественно, раз зависла сама программа *linux*, запустить программу *dmesg* и посмотреть содержимое буфера, увы, не удастся.

остаётся надежда на то, что продолжает работать установленная у вас в системе реализация *syslog-демона* (часто — *rsyslog*) и всё ещё функционирует дисковая подсистема. благодаря чему информация из кольцевого буфера записывается в `/var/log/dmesg` и/или `/var/log/kern.log`.

в этих файлах и стоит в первую очередь искать информацию о неполадках. учтите только, что в процессе загрузки старый файл `/var/log/dmesg` будет переименован во что-нибудь вроде `/var/log/dmesg.0`, а в `/var/log/dmesg` будут записываться сообщения, начиная с текущей загрузки системы.

Comment: linux - это не программа, а набор программ, ядро (программа и драйвера) + загружаемые драйевра + демона(программы) + пользовательские приложения(программы). "зависнуть" (для пользователя, смотрящего глазами на компьютер, можно в любой из этих программ)

Comment: @strangeqargo, ни «демоны», ни «пользовательские приложения» невозможно отнести к программе *linux*. если вас смущает определение «программа, выполняющая функции ядра операционной системы», смело можете вместо «программа» использовать слово «библиотека». теоретически, программу *linux* можно было бы назвать и неким «набором программ». если из [опубликованных её исходников](https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.6.1.tar.xz) можно было бы их собрать. насколько мне известно, из этих исходников можно собрать лишь одну программу.

Comment: нет никакой программы "linux", есть загрузчик (он мог зависнуть) есть ядро ( с драйверами), могло ядро зависнуть (из-за драйвера), есть демона (они могли зависнуть или создать иллюзию зависания, при инициализации).  есть пользовательские программы, Если вы называете ядро "программой линукс", то у вас очень странные представления об архитектурных терминах

Comment: @strangeqargo, «программа (библиотека), выполняющая функции ядра операционной системы» — по-моему, вполне чёткое и однозначное определение. что в этом определении может не соответствовать реальному положению дел — для меня, увы, неясно. // к слову: загрузчики (grub, lilo, sysllinux и т.д. и т.п.) — это совершенно самостоятельные программы, не имеющие прямого отношения к исходникам программы *linux*.

Comment: человек спрашивает почему у него система виснет, вы ему задвигаете про "программу linux". Нет такой программы. Linux - название семейства операционных систем.

Comment: @strangeqargo, я описал то, что, судя по вопросу и комментариям, наблюдает автор вопроса. по поводу того, в какой именно части программы *linux* (управление фс, памятью, процессами, сетью, оборудованием и т.д. и т.п.) **могли** возникнуть неполадки, как вы видите, я не написал ни слова. а лишь привёл инструкции, где именно можно увидеть информацию, которая (возможно) позволит сделать выводы о месте возникновения неполадок.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Конечно, формально говоря, ядро Linux это программа. Но так его никто не называет, это некорректное словоупотребление. Да и в любом случае ответы SO не для придирок к лексике.

Comment: @uhbif19, *ответы SO не для придирок к лексике* — полностью согласен. впрочем, я не считаю замечания, полученные мною от strangeqargo «придирками».